# How can i convert a virtual box vdi and install it on an actual hard drive partition?

Tags: virtualbox, virtual

I plan to run this to create an image
    VBoxManage internalcommands converttoraw your-virtualbox-disk.vdi /dev/sdX

I have an employ partition ready but I also already have 1 Linux partition and 2 windows partitions losing from a grub boot loader.
This IMG would be the 4th partition (also windows).
How can I get it to boot properly?

Answer (score 2):

Convert it to raw image using the following command

VBoxManage.exe clonehd --format RAW source.vdi destination.img

Then use this tool http://hddguru.com/software/HDD-Raw-Copy-Tool/ to copy img to HDD

Comment: How do I get Linux to pick it up in the boot menu? Also, will windows reconfigure the drivers and hardware?